# Compiling Single Trilinos Example: e.g. Anasazi or Belos

Tags: trilinos

I have built Trilinos multiple times, trying out few possibilities.
I see that the examples are built after the long compiling.

Instead of building again the whole packages, I want to compile just a single C++ (.cpp) file, for example BlockDavidson for Anasazi with Epetra: [Anasazi](https://github.com/trilinos/Trilinos/blob/master/packages/anasazi/epetra/example/BlockDavidson/BlockDavidsonEpetra.cpp)

or BlockCG for Belos with Epetra:
[Belos](https://github.com/trilinos/Trilinos/blob/master/packages/belos/epetra/example/BlockCG/BlockCGEpetraExFile.cpp)

The question is simple:

1. Can I compile them with simple gcc -o test BlockCGEpetraExFile.cpp ?
   I tried it but it returned 'undefined reference'
   [Error gcc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeC7g.png)
   Do I lack some other syntaxes?
2. If there is a Makefile or something similar that anyone ever created that can be edited for any package in Trilinos?

Comment: The files that you want to build rely on include files and functionality of other parts of the package. It looks like each package has cmake support. So what more do you need?

Comment: I know now, I have made it to create the compiling works for single example / .cpp file